# How Do You Check if an Entry Is in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I check if an entry is in a pandas DataFrame? For example, say

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,2,3], 'B' : [4,5,6], 'C' : [7,8,9]})
```

How do I check if the entry `1,4` exists in an entry under columns `A,B`, regardless of what is in `C`?

Comment: you can use `isin` function in pandas

Comment: Would the best way be `df[ df.A.isin( [1,] ) & df.B.isin( [4,] ) ].values.size == 0`? Otherwise, I get an error `Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a dictionary (to [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)) with the values to search by column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})
result = df.isin({'A': [1], 'B': [4]})
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
       A      B
0   True   True
1  False  False
2  False  False
```

Afterwards you can find if the entry exists using [all](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
result = df.isin({'A': [1], 'B': [4]}).all(1)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
```

To use it in an if statement, and just on the columns `['A', 'B']`, use [any](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html#pandas.Series.any), for example:

```
if df[['A', 'B']].isin({'A': [1], 'B': [4]}).all(1).any():
    print('found')
```

Comment: How do I use this in an `if` statement though? Do I need to then use `.values.any()`?

Comment: What if you have more columns? This doesn't work if, say, you added a third column 'C' with values [7,8,9]. What would you do then? Would I slice it to just `df[['A','B']]`? (Can you update your answer and I'll accept it.)